# react-admin, custom reducer to manipulate data inside state.admin

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-admin

I want to inject a custom reducer into react-admin to manipulate data inside `state.admin`.

There is a section in [doc](https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/blob/master/docs/Admin.md#customreducers) for adding a custom reducer but this reducer can handle its own namespace.

How can I access and change data inside `state.admin`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't update data in another Redux reducer if the store was created using `combineReducer()` - which is the case in react-admin. That's a design decision by Redux.

In your case, you have 2 possibilities:

- Add a middleware (or a custom saga) that will redispatch an action based on your action. That will allow you to dispatch react-admin actions (like CRUD_DELETE_SUCCESS) that actually update the store. That way, you'll be able to (indirectly) update any part of the store.
- add a reducer that listens to react-admin actions and stores the related data. that means you'll *copy* the react-admin reducer data in another custom reducer.